# Is it possible to catch errors and execute a code without Else using Try only or with conditionals?

Tags: python, exception, conditional-statements

I was wondering if we can execute our code entirely in the `try` section without using `else`.
Obviously it works. here is an example:

```
x = int(input())
try:
  print(10/x)
  print("Possible")

except ZeroDivisionError as e:
 print(e)
```

Or we can do this which is the mostly used syntax:

```
x = int(input())
try:
  print(10/x)

except ZeroDivisionError as e:
  print(e)

else:
  print("Possible")
```

We can even use a condition in this case:

```
x = int(input())

if x !=0:
  print(10/x)
  print("possible")

elif x ==0 :
  print("Error!")
```

So what is the difference between these three? which one should be used? all three seem to be able to catch and prevent errors.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the first one. Here's the reason. When you use a `try-except` block you get the control over the exception and you can display custom messages along with the stack trace. The second one is not very readable and a little redundant (after all why do you want to display any message if everything went fine!) and the third one doesn't show where and how the error occurred. If that is not your concern, any of these would work just fine.

Comment: What if the input was inside `try` and i wanted to print the division result like `print(10/x)`? , should this print statement be inside try or inside else?

Comment: No. It ideally shouldn't be in there if you don;t want to catch any errors in the input. `try-except` block only take the part of the code for which you want to do error handling. Here, you don't want to handle any errors occurred while the user inputs something so it shouldn't go in the try-except block

Comment: Ok then, lets say we have the input outside the block and we define a variable like `result =10/x` inside `try` .  Now if i want to print `result` where should the print statement be? Whithin `try` (toghether with `result = 10/x` or separately inside `else`? Both way seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

It is better if try-except is used, because you may not always be able to master all errors. For example, if the user enters a "String" you will still get an error.

You can also catch the error you want with the "except" command. And you can see where the error is.